# Concatenar vários arquivos de texto com quebras de linhas em Batch Script

Tags: bat

##### Alguém pode me dizer se posso adicionar uma quebra de linha, para cada conteúdo de cada arquivo?

Por exemplo, em um arquivo existe o conteúdo **cachorro** e em outros arquivos existem demais tipos de conteúdos, porém os arquivos não possuem quebra de linha no final, assim, **concatenando-os** na mesma linha.

1. **Exemplo incorreto**

> *cachorro gato zebra*

2. **Exemplo correto**

> *cachorro
> gato
> zebra*

É possível isto?

Comment: Como você está lendo esses arquivos? Posta o código.

Comment: você pode adicionar o & para obter a quebra... sem ver seu código é difícil ajudar mas ficaria mais ou menos:
echo cachorro & echo gato & echo zebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os comandos abaixo num arquivo `.bat`.

Criando arquivo de *comandos em lote* `.bat`:

**1.** Abra o Bloco de Notas e copie o código abaixo.

**2.** Salve o arquivo e feche o Bloco de Notas.

**3.** Renomeie o arquivo que acabou de salvar mudando a extensão de `.txt` para `.bat`.

**4.** Agora basta dar dois cliques no arquivo `.bat` para executá-lo.

> Para juntar os arquivos `.txt` que quiser, eles devem estar no mesmo
>   diretório do arquivo `.bat`.

**Código:**

```
del juntos.txt

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    type %%I >> juntos.tmp
    echo. >> juntos.tmp
)

ren juntos.tmp juntos.txt
```

### EDIT

Para mover o arquivo final para outro diretório (pasta), inclua o código abaixo no fim do `.bat`:

```
move juntos.txt D:\nome_da_pasta/
```

Se for uma subpasta de onde o `.bat` está, basta:

```
move juntos.txt nome_da_pasta/
```

Comment: Opa eu tenho que executar todos esses comandos ao mesmo tempo, pois sou leigo nisso?

Comment: @marcelo Editei a pergunta com o passo a passo. Boa sorte!

Comment: Bah muito bom, valeu mesmo deu certo, abraço!!!

Comment: teria como nesse mesmo bat eu dar um destino onde eu quero que salve este arquivo?

Comment: @marcelo acho que tem como sim, perai...

Comment: @marcelo Coloquei na resposta como fazer isso. Basta mover o arquivo gerado. Abs!